# How to free up block device that is mounted to an inaccessible place?

Tags: linux, mount, umount

```
root@vi-notebook:~# cat /proc/mounts | grep raidy
/dev/md0 /root/e/i/wpc2/boot/mnt/raidy reiserfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime 0 0

root@vi-notebook:~# umount -n /root/e/i/wpc2/boot/mnt/raidy
umount: /root/e/i/wpc2/boot/mnt/raidy: Transport endpoint is not connected

root@vi-notebook:~# mount /dev/md/raidy /mnt/raidy/ -t reiserfs -o nodev,nosuid,noexec,acl,noatime
mount: /dev/md0 already mounted or /mnt/raidy/ busy
```

The only workaround I found is:

```
root@vi-notebook:~# losetup /dev/loop0 /dev/md/raidy 
root@vi-notebook:~# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/raidy/ -t reiserfs -o nodev,nosuid,noexec,acl,noatime
```

Comment: What happens if you umount /dev/md0 ?

Comment: @Linker3000, The same. If it is not found in /etc/mtab then `not mounted`; if found - `/root/e/i/wpc2/boot/mnt/raidy: Transport endpoint is not connected` "man 2 umount" tells that `In Linux 2.3.99-pre7 the call umount(device) was removed, leaving only umount(dir)`. And it really tried to umount that directory (as `strace` says), failing: `oldumount("/root/e/itransition/wpc2/boot/mnt/raidy") = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)`